# number of rows affected in HiveQL

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, cloudera-cdh

is there a way to get the rows affected count after running CTAS in hive?

I am running a

create table t1 as  select * from t2 where ... ;

Basically , I would like to print the num of rows in new table for logging purposes.

Thanks!

Comment: How about some feedback on offered answer(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Hive does report number of rows affected as part of CTAS: see example here:

```
Table default.errors2 stats: [num_partitions: 0, num_files: 1, num_rows: 860, total_size: 17752, raw_data_size: 16892]
```

More details of the output:

```
hive> create table errors2 as select * from errors;
..
Stage-5 is filtered out by condition resolver.
Moving data to: hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/hive-steve/hive_2014-12-13_06-00-40_553_7396982929134959624/-ext-10001
Moving data to: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/errors2
Table default.errors2 stats: [num_partitions: 0, num_files: 1, num_rows: 860, total_size: 17752, raw_data_size: 16892]
OK
dayandhour  dowandhour  cnt
Time taken: 7.348 seconds
```

**UPDATE** OP asked about saving the rowcount in a variable.  There is not a builtin hive command AFAIK. You could however run the command from the command line via

```
hive -e "<hivesql>"  | grep "[num_partitions]" | <regex command to isolate the num_rows>
```

Comment: Thank you. is there a way i can store the number of rows effected into a variable if i want to store the history in a logging table.

Comment: Updated answer for this for suggestion how to obtain the rowcount